# What's the meaning of "I felt very much a child"?

Tags: meaning

I searched the Google but it didn't help me. so,

Would you please explain it to me?

The full text is here:

> "I was only ten, and in that moment **I felt very much a child**. Luke was my
>   big brother; I thought he would know what to do"

Comment: I felt like a child, quite simply. But, one say: to feel very much a [stranger, child, foreigner, friend, etc. etc.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subject here is referring to his emotions. Children are inexperienced, and can become scared/overwhelmed in unfamiliar situations. Thus, he *"felt very much [like] a child"*, not only because he was a child, but because his emotions in that particular situation identified with those of a child.

The construction "to feel a..." is not uncommon. See the below examples:

> I felt a failure, because I lost the fight.
>
> He felt very much a king, after buying his first mansion.

Answer (score 1):

We understand that to mean:

I felt very much (that) I was a child.

I felt (myself to be) a child.

I was *very aware* at that moment that I was (only) a child.